# I is equal to the preimage of its image.

Tags: ring-theory

> **Lemma.** Let $f$ be a homomorphism from the ring $R$ onto the ring $R'$.
>   If $I$ is any ideal of $R$ such that $\ker(f)$ is a subset of $I$, then $I = f^{-1}(f(I))$.

I am trying to understand this proof given in my ring theory text:

> **Proof.** Suppose that the element $a$ is in $f^{-1}(f(I))$, so that $f(a)$ is in $f(I)$.  Then $f(a) = f(r)$ for some choice of $r$ in $I$. As a result, we will have $f(a - r) = 0$, or, what amounts to the same thing, $a - r$ is in $\ker(f)$, which is a subset of $I$. This implies that $a$ is in $I$.

I understand everything up to and including: $a - r$ is in $\ker(f)$, which is a subset of $I$.  But I do not see how this implies that $a$ is in $I$.

Comment: When it comes to writing your questions, you might find this helpful: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $a-r\in I$ and $r\in I$. $I$ is an ideal, so it’s closed under addition, and therefore $a=(a-r)+r\in I$.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  But now I have another question. The lemma states that the homomorphism R is ONTO R'.  I do not see where in this proof that it is necessary that f be surjective.

Comment: @Geoffrey: You’re welcome. You’re quite right: it isn’t necessary.